# Laravel Custom Clause

Tags: laravel-5

Am trying to understand how the **whereListing_type** custom clause was created in Laravel but could not find any information on it so far

DB::table('property')
->join('auction', 'property.id', '=', 'auction.property_id')
->leftJoin('auctioneer_notes', 'property.id', '=', 'auctioneer_notes.property_id')
->**whereListing_type**('weauction')

**Here is my Property Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Property extends Model
{
  //
  protected $table = 'property';
  protected $guarded = ['id'];

  use SoftDeletes;

  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public static $rules =
    [
        'country' => 'required',
        'province' => 'required',
        'suburb_town_city' => 'required',
        'area' => 'required',
        'property_type' => 'required',
        'listing_type' => 'required',
        'land_measurement' => 'required_if:land_size,==,true',
    ];

public static $rules2 =
    [
        'lead_image' => 'required',
        'image_gallery' => 'required',
        'short_descrip' => 'required',
        'long_descrip' => 'required',
        'attourney' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ];


public $errors;

public function farm()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Farm::class);
}

public function featured()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Featured::class);
}

public function residential()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Residential::class);
}
public function commercial()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Commercial::class);
}

public function own_attourney()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Ownattourney::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function vetting()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Vetting::class);
}

public function auction()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Auction::class);
}

public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attributes::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('value');
}


//Check if Property has Attribute
public function hasAttribute($name)
{

    foreach ($this->features as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->name == $name)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function getFeatureValue($name, $property_id)
{
    $query = 'SELECT value FROM attributes
                INNER JOIN attributes_property
                ON attributes.id = attributes_id
                WHERE name = "' . $name . '"
                AND property_id = "' . $property_id . '"';

    return DB::select($query);
}

public function getFeatureValuebyType($name, $property_id, $type)
{
    $query = 'SELECT value FROM attributes
                INNER JOIN attributes_property
                ON attributes.id = attributes_id
                WHERE name = "' . $name . '"
                AND property_id = "' . $property_id . '"
                AND type = "' . $type . '"';

    return DB::select($query);
}

  //Assign a Attribute to A Property
  public function assignAttribute($attribute, $value)
  {

      if (!is_numeric($attribute)) {
        $attributeDetails = DB::select('SELECT id FROM attributes WHERE attributes.name = "' . $attribute . '"');
        $attribute = $attributeDetails[0];
      }
      return $this->features()->attach($attribute, ['value' => $value]);
  }

  public function ammendAttribute($attributes_id, $property_id, $value)
  {

     $query = 'UPDATE attributes_property SET value = "' . $value . '" WHERE attributes_id = "' . $attributes_id . '"
    AND property_id = "' . $property_id . '"';

     return DB::update($query);

  }

  //Remove a Role from a User
  public function removeAttribute($attribute)
  {
     if (!is_numeric($attribute)) {
         $attributeDetails = DB::select('SELECT id FROM attributes WHERE attributes.name = "' . $attribute . '"');
         $attribute = $attributeDetails[0];
      }
      return $this->features()->detach($attribute);
  }

  public function isValid()
  {

      $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules);

      if($validation->fails()){
          $this->errors = $validation->errors();
          return false; 
      }
      else{
          return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your `Property` model class codes as well?

Answer (score 0):

1st: do not mix camel case and snake case in function names

2nd: prefer using standard fluent style over magic

correct your function ...

either (not preferred):

```
**>whereListingType('weauction')**
```

or (preferred):

```
**->where('listing_type', '=', 'weauction')**
```

you can also leave out the "="

```
**->where('listing_type', 'weauction')**
```

best documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses